# unable to decode json variable

Tags: php, json

I have following piece of code which is generating JSON variable. I use php built in `json_decode` function to decode the json variable but i am getting NULL after decoding JSOn variable.

```
$a=array("targetAction"=>"getHeadFields","targetHead"=>$table_name);
$obj1 =  Post_Uamsdata($a);
echo $obj1;

$file = json_decode($obj1,true);
var_dump($file);
```

$obj1 is my json variable. whenever i echo it i get the result as follows:

```
{"success":"yes","error":"","message":"","arguments":"[{\"fieldNo\":\"1\",\"fieldName\":\"ItemType\",\"fieldType\":\"character(16)\",\"notnull\":\"f\",\"fieldLabel\":null,\"primary_key\":\"f\",\"default\":null,\"fieldOption\":[]},{\"fieldNo\":\"2\",\"fieldName\":\"Long\",\"fieldType\":\"character(20)\",\"notnull\":\"f\",\"fieldLabel\":null,\"primary_key\":\"f\",\"default\":null,\"fieldOption\":[]},{\"fieldNo\":\"3\",\"fieldName\":\"Lat\",\"fieldType\":\"character(20)\",\"notnull\":\"f\",\"fieldLabel\":null,\"primary_key\":\"f\",\"default\":null,\"fieldOption\":[]},{\"fieldNo\":\"4\",\"fieldName\":\"MapDate\",\"fieldType\":\"character(16)\",\"notnull\":\"f\",\"fieldLabel\":null,\"primary_key\":\"f\",\"default\":null,\"fieldOption\":[]},{\"fieldNo\":\"5\",\"fieldName\":\"FieldNote\",\"fieldType\":\"character(64)\",\"notnull\":\"f\",\"fieldLabel\":null,\"primary_key\":\"f\",\"default\":null,\"fieldOption\":[]}]"}
```

i have checked it in online json validator and it is saying that this JSOn is valid. But whenever i decode this $obj1 into $file then i am always getting NULL.

Comment: Could not reproduce - assuming your function `Post_Uamsdata` produces the JSON string you claim, it decodes successfully: [gist](https://gist.github.com/customanything/6680625)

Comment: Please share the code for Post_Uamsdata()

Comment: It's only possible if the entire JSON string is appended with a semicolon (;). So, I guess you should do: $file = json_decode(rtrim($obj1, ';'),true); Let me know.

Comment: Can you upload the code in a server so that we can look at the JSON returned?

Comment: JSON result return $obj1 i have posted the result plz see it

Comment: I saw that. At my end, it's not producing NULL. It's parsing is correct. Only possibility to get a NULL for a malformed JSON string. That's why I wanted to see it online.

Comment: ok tell me how to upload this is server?

Comment: @MuneemHabib Upload scripts through FTP, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

after `json_decode` we get the following, But I guess this is not what you want. You want the fieldNo, fieldName etc also to be parsed.

```
  $json = '{"success":"yes","error":"","message":"","arguments":"[{\"fieldNo\":\"1\",\"fieldName\":\"ItemType\",\"fieldType\":\"character(16)\",\"notnull\":\"f\",\"fieldLabel\":null,\"primary_key\":\"f\",\"default\":null,\"fieldOption\":[]},{\"fieldNo\":\"2\",\"fieldName\":\"Long\",\"fieldType\":\"character(20)\",\"notnull\":\"f\",\"fieldLabel\":null,\"primary_key\":\"f\",\"default\":null,\"fieldOption\":[]},{\"fieldNo\":\"3\",\"fieldName\":\"Lat\",\"fieldType\":\"character(20)\",\"notnull\":\"f\",\"fieldLabel\":null,\"primary_key\":\"f\",\"default\":null,\"fieldOption\":[]},{\"fieldNo\":\"4\",\"fieldName\":\"MapDate\",\"fieldType\":\"character(16)\",\"notnull\":\"f\",\"fieldLabel\":null,\"primary_key\":\"f\",\"default\":null,\"fieldOption\":[]},{\"fieldNo\":\"5\",\"fieldName\":\"FieldNote\",\"fieldType\":\"character(64)\",\"notnull\":\"f\",\"fieldLabel\":null,\"primary_key\":\"f\",\"default\":null,\"fieldOption\":[]}]"}';

 $arr = json_decode($json, true);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($arr);
```

Output is as follows

```
 Array
 (
   [success] => yes
   [error] => 
   [message] => 
   [arguments] =>  [{"fieldNo":"1","fieldName":"ItemType","fieldType":"character(16)","notnull":"f","fieldLabel":null,"primary_key":"f","default":null,"fieldOption":[]},{"fieldNo":"2","fieldName":"Long","fieldType":"character(20)","notnull":"f","fieldLabel":null,"primary_key":"f","default":null,"fieldOption":[]},{"fieldNo":"3","fieldName":"Lat","fieldType":"character(20)","notnull":"f","fieldLabel":null,"primary_key":"f","default":null,"fieldOption":[]},{"fieldNo":"4","fieldName":"MapDate","fieldType":"character(16)","notnull":"f","fieldLabel":null,"primary_key":"f","default":null,"fieldOption":[]},{"fieldNo":"5","fieldName":"FieldNote","fieldType":"character(64)","notnull":"f","fieldLabel":null,"primary_key":"f","default":null,"fieldOption":[]}]
  )
```

Comment: i have also checked it by hardcoding values it is working fine but it gives me NULL when i decode JSON object

Comment: its returning the same string which i have copied.

Answer (score 0):

As http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php indicates that the function will only work for UTF-8 encoded string, try the following:

```
$file = json_decode(mb_convert_encoding($obj1, 'UTF-8'),true);
```

Comment: still not getting anything